# Android Linphone can't make registration

Tags: android, linphone

I'm using SIP in android application but my current library can't provide some functions for me. So i try to use android-linphone lib and get some confusion. I do not understand how to make registration on Asterisk with this library.
 Native library is loaded well

```
I/LinphoneCoreFactoryImpl﹕ Trying to load liblinphone for armeabi-v7a
I/LinphoneCoreFactoryImpl﹕ Loading done with armeabi-v7a
Has neon: true
Has ZRTP: true
```

i'm trying to create user as saying on this page [liblinphone-javadoc](http://www.linphone.org/docs/liblinphone-javadoc/)

in my code example
    activity implements `LinphoneCoreListener`

```
LinphoneCoreListener linphoneCoreListener = this;

    try {
        mLinphoneCore = LinphoneCoreFactoryImpl.instance().createLinphoneCore(this, this);
        mLinphoneCore.setNetworkReachable(true);
    } catch (LinphoneCoreException e) {
        System.out.println("LinphoneCoreException  " + e.toString());
    }

    LinphoneProxyConfig proxy_cfg;
    LinphoneAuthInfo info;

    info = LinphoneCoreFactory.instance().createAuthInfo(mUserName, mUserName, mUserPass, null, null, mDomain); /*create authentication structure from identity*/
    mLinphoneCore.addAuthInfo(info); /*add authentication info to LinphoneCore*/

    /*create proxy config*/
    try {
        proxy_cfg = mLinphoneCore.createProxyConfig(mSipUser, mDomain, mDomain, true);
        proxy_cfg.setIdentity(mSipUser); /*set identity with user name and domain*/
        proxy_cfg.setProxy(mDomain); /* we assume domain = proxy server address*/
        proxy_cfg.enableRegister(true); /*activate registration for this proxy config*/
        mLinphoneCore.addProxyConfig(proxy_cfg); /*add proxy config to linphone core*/
        mLinphoneCore.setDefaultProxyConfig(proxy_cfg); /*set to default proxy*/
        mLinphoneCore.addListener(linphoneCoreListener);
        proxy_cfg.done();

        System.out.println("Proxy state is = " + proxy_cfg.getState());/*23838-23838/com.myapplication I/System.out﹕ Proxy state is = RegistrationNone*/
    } catch (LinphoneCoreException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
```

`LinphoneCoreListener` messages

```
I/System.out﹕ globalState Starting up
I/System.out﹕ configuringStatus null
I/System.out﹕ displayStatus Ready
I/System.out﹕ globalState Ready
```

In docs says that `configuringStatus message` the error message if state == Failed, but nothing about `null`.

I'll be really greatful for help with this library.

Answer (score 2):

After configuration, you have to call `LinphoneCore.iterate()` periodically in loop. This is main application loop. For example, from Linphone app sources:

```
    mLc = LinphoneCoreFactory.instance().createLinphoneCore(...);

    TimerTask lTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            UIThreadDispatcher.dispatch(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (mLc != null) {
                        mLc.iterate();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    mTimer = new Timer("Linphone scheduler");
    mTimer.schedule(lTask, 0, 20);
```